# Ci : GIT + Jenkins + MSBUILD Build Error

Tags: asp.net, git, jenkins, msbuild

I want to set up a continuous integration platform. ( VS2010 (2.0,3.5), GIT, JENKINS, MSBUILD ) Then IIS if Build OK

The technical environment is Microsoft ( ASP.NET => VB.Net & c# )

The Jenkins installation is OK

Sources management is ensured by Git ( Commits and push are OK )

When the push is made, Jenkins examines the warehouse GIT then performs automaticly with Ms Build.
But the Build is still error and i really don't understand why (sry i'm french ):

> **C:\Users\d*********.metaproj : error MSB6006: stop " aspnet_compiler.exe" with code 1. Génération  projet
>   "C:\Users\d*********.metaproj"-- ÉCHEC.**

Is the .sln files the probleme ? i Never configure this file because that's OK on local IIS and if i manually add projet on IIS Server Its Ok too ( WS2003)

Is it possible to compile with MSBUILD only the root directory of the solution (without the .sln file) ?
Is it possible to perform a Build with "ASPNET Compile" without the solution is in the IIS ?

Thank you for your answers